# Can I use MX Record Configuration to send one account's email to one server and a second account's email to a different server?

Tags: email, email-server, mx-record, email-bounces

For example, let's say my MX Record(s) specify:

`0 server1 mydomainexample.com`

`1 server2 mydomainexample.com`

Now let's say:

`me@mydomainexample.com is an account on server1`

and

`you@mydomainexample.com  is an account on server2`

Will the sender try to send you@mydomainexample.com mail on server1 and fail over to server2?

Comment: No it won't. If you want to do this you'll need to set up SMTP namespace sharing.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down vote ?

Comment: Mouseover the arrow: "*this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the values at the start of your records are [MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) preference values. Preference values are used to advise servers wishing to deliver mail to example.com which is the preferred host to deliver to. The lower the value the more preferred the host is.

In your example mail will only be delivered to server2 if server 1 is unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

No. If you need to do this you will need a mail-aware application running on `:25` on the servers that are the targets for the `MX` records that can sort out where to deliver or forward the mail to.

Answer (score 0):

fyi, `MX` record is for *INCOMING* mails and not for outgoing, you might want to spend some time reading more into it so that you'll understand it better: [MX record - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record)